# String processing in Javascript using Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, split

Here is the input that should be converted to JSON format as given below.

```
'{RS0004036}:{1;2}:{0000003AB;0000003BC}_{RS0004036}:{0;3}:{0000003DE;0000003FG}_{RS0004036}:{3;3}:{0000003HI;0000003JK}'
```

Target JSON should be like this. The code should read the above input, will create a JSON return string as follows. The returning JSON will return store which will be only one value of the index 0 of the input string and will not repeat as partList.

```
"storeList": [
                {
                    "store": "RS0004036",
                    "partList": [
                        {
                            "part": "0000003AB",
                            "partSub": "0000003BC",
                            "qtyOnHand": "0",
                            "qtyMinMax": "3"
                        },
                               {
                            "part": "0000003DE",
                            "partSub": "0000003FG",
                            "qtyOnHand": "3",
                            "qtyMinMax": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "part": "0000003HI",
                            "partSub": "0000003JK",
                            "qtyOnHand": "1",
                            "qtyMinMax": "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

I tried the following code:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function replaceAll(search, replace) {
  return this.split(search).join(replace);
}
var storeList = {};
var partList = [];
storeList.partList = partList;
var hdr_str = '{RS0004036}:{1;2}:{0000003AB;0000003BC}_{RS0004036}:{0;3}:{0000003DE;0000003FG}_{RS0004036}:{3;3}:{0000003HI;0000003JK}';
var sites_ar = [];
var str_array = hdr_str.split('_');

var str_us = [];
var qty_ar = [];
var hdr_parts = [];

var part_semi = [];
var part_detail = [];

function populate_part(str_in) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
    if (str_array[i] !== '"') {
      var str_colon = str_array[i];

      if (str_colon !== '"') {
        if (str_colon !== undefined) {
          const part_detail = str_colon.split(':');
          storeList.store = part_detail[0]
            partList = {
            "part": part_detail[0],
            "qtyOnHand": part_detail[1],
            "qtyMinMax": part_detail[2]
          }
          storeList.partList.push(partList);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
pattern = ';';
replacement = ',';
hdr_str = hdr_str.replaceAll(pattern, replacement);
pattern = ':';
replacement = ',';
hdr_str = hdr_str.replaceAll(pattern, replacement);
hdr_str = '[' + hdr_str + ']';

for (var i = 0; i < hdr_str.length; i++) {
  if (str_array[i] !== '"') {
    populate_part(str_array[i]);
  }
}
retun(JSON.stringify(storeList));
```

But it is returning duplicates, not sure where is the issue.

```
{"partList":[{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{0;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003DE;0000003FG}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{1;2}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003AB;0000003BC}"},{"part":"{RS0004036}","qtyOnHand":"{3;3}","qtyMinMax":"{0000003HI;0000003JK}"}],"store":"{RS0004036}"}
```

Comment: `But it is returning duplicates, not sure where is the issue.` probably all those globals - though, most of the global `var` are unused - so it's probably the one you use

Comment: `str_array[i] !== '"'` will be true for every single character  in your `hdr_string` and every single element in your `str_array`, because it doesn't contain any quotes ...  Furhtermore, you are iterating `i` over the length of `hdr_string` and then accessing `str_string[i]`, but `str_string` will have fewer elements than `hdr_string` has characters. Why are you even iterating over `hdr_string`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you debug your current code, because I don't understand it. I've refactored it, to produce the result you were looking for.

We use `str.slice(1, -1))` to remove the `{}` around the data values. And then it's as simple as splitting it apart and adding it to the array.

```js
const hdr_str = '{RS0004036}:{1;2}:{0000003AB;0000003BC}_{RS0004036}:{0;3}:{0000003DE;0000003FG}_{RS0004036}:{3;3}:{0000003HI;0000003JK}';
const stores = [];

const partsDataEntries = hdr_str.split('_');
partsDataEntries.forEach(entry => {
  const partsData = entry.split(':').map(str => str.slice(1, -1));
  const storeId = partsData[0];
  const [qtyOnHand, qtyMinMax] = partsData[1].split(';');
  const [part, partSub] = partsData[2].split(';');
  
  if(!stores.find(store => store.store == storeId)) {
    stores.push({
      store: storeId,
      partList: []
    })
  }
  
  const store = stores.find(store => store.store == storeId);
  store.partList.push({
    part,
    partSub,
    qtyOnHand,
    qtyMinMax
  });
  
});

console.log(stores);
```

Updated answer without `.forEach()` or `.map()`

```js
var hdr_str = '{RS0004036}:{1;2}:{0000003AB;0000003BC}_{RS0004036}:{0;3}:{0000003DE;0000003FG}_{RS0004036}:{3;3}:{0000003HI;0000003JK}';
var stores = [];

var partsDataEntries = hdr_str.split('_');
for (var i = 0; i < partsDataEntries.length; i++) {
  var entry = partsDataEntries[i];
  var parts = entry.split(':');
  var partsData = [];
  
  for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
    partsData.push(parts[j].slice(1, -1));
  }
  
  var storeId = partsData[0];
  var qtyData = partsData[1].split(';');
  var qtyOnHand = qtyData[0];
  var qtyMinMax = qtyData[1];
  var partData = partsData[2].split(';');
  var part = partData[0];
  var partSub = partData[1];

  var storeFound = false;
  for (var k = 0; k < stores.length; k++) {
    if (stores[k].store == storeId) {
      storeFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (!storeFound) {
    stores.push({
      store: storeId,
      partList: []
    });
  }
  
  var store;
  for (var l = 0; l < stores.length; l++) {
    if (stores[l].store == storeId) {
      store = stores[l];
      break;
    }
  }
  
  store.partList.push({
    part: part,
    partSub: partSub,
    qtyOnHand: qtyOnHand,
    qtyMinMax: qtyMinMax
  });
}

console.log(stores);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Steffen. Seems map function and partsDataEntries.forEach, is not supported in the javascript (old) version I am working on. Any alternative using like for (var i = 0; i < hdr_str.length; i++) loop.

Comment: @Curo yes, I've updated my answer. Polyfills could also have worked.